# Unexpected behavior in Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I have two activities `Activity 1` and `Activity 2`. I am starting `Activity 2` from `Activity 1` and when `Activity 2` finishes, `Activity 1` will be resumed. But sometimes `Activity 2` finishes unexpectedly(it is not throwing any exceptions) and `Activity 1` is started again. Should I specify any `FLAGS` for intent when starting `Activity 2`?
I am creating `Activity 2` by using below code:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SyncService.class);   
 startActivity(intent);
```

I am using many threads in `Activity 2`. Will it create any problems?

Comment: You should post the cod from your activity2, without it we cant see what the problem is...

Comment: @kiran show your activity2 code.

Comment: Actually `Activity 2` code is pretty big(nearly 1000 lines). That's why I haven't posted it.

Comment: activities don't finish unexpectedly. either you are finishing it yourself or android is killing it off (probably because of an ANR). Look in your logcat (don't filter the logcat) and you will probably see something about ANR (Application Not Responding).

Answer (score 1):

Start Activity2 with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SyncService.class);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

And in Activity1, override:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //do your thing here
    //this is called when Activity2 finishes
    //see below
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    }
}
```

In Activity2, when you're ready to finish, call:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
//if you want, you can pass some data back to Activity1
resultIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

which will get you back to Activity2.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).